# Google Fonts latin extended not working

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-font-api

There is an issue when browsing Google Fonts gallery, for example https://fonts.google.com/?category=Handwriting&subset=latin

When you type a custom demo text inclufing latin extended characters and apply it to all fonts, many of them render those characters in a right way! Nevertheless after selecting the font they tend to loose the latin extended subset and also it cannot be used on the website which imports the font.

What is the reason for such behaviour? And how do Google render latin-ext right by first?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Imprima&display=swap&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```

Your code is missing "subset=latin-ext", please see the code above.

Comment: The `subset` parameter was deprecated. Any ideas how to get this to work again?